# What is a good python design pattern for polymorphic functions across sets of class versions: intersections, unions, and differences?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of objects that are all very similar, and my current method of explicitly writing the same function for each object is not scaling well as I add new objects to the playing field.

Each of my weapons has a properties dictionary:

```
class Sword(Item):
    def __init__():
        self.properties = {"Blade": True, "Attack": 30, "Defense": 5, "Type": "standard"}

class Dagger(Item):
    def __init__():
        self.properties = {"Blade": True, "Attack": 20, "Type": "stealth"}

class Pistol(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {"Firearm": True, "Attack": 20, "Type": "stealth"}

class Wooden_shield(Item):
    def __init__():
        self.properties = {"Shield": True, "Defense": 30, "Type": "standard"}
```

In my battle code, I would like to do something like this:

```
best_attack_item = None
for item in inventory:
    attack_power = item.properties.get("Attack")
    if best_attack_item:
        if attack_power > best_attack_item.get("Attack"):
            best_attack_item = item


best_attack_item.attack() # I would like attack() to automatically do what is correct
```

So this is my dummy solution below. How can I make it scale better? I am getting upwards of 30 attack items to deal with, and it will keep growing over time. I don't want to write and maintain the attack code more than once per variation of it.

**Bad Solution**

```
class Sword(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {"Blade": True, "Attack": 30, "Defense": 5, "Type": "standard"}
    def attack(self):
        print("attacking with blade!")

class Dagger(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {"Blade": True, "Attack": 20, "Type": "stealth"}
    def attack(self):
        print("attacking with blade!")

class Pistol(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {"Firearm": True, "Attack": 20, "Type": "stealth"}
    def attack(self):
        print("Firing!")

class Wooden_shield(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {"Shield": True, "Defense": 30, "Type": "standard"}
```

I was thinking one method of keeping track of all the subsets of properties may be something like shown below. I like this as I think it will be easier to manage the sets. However, something about it still feels bad. How can this be better?

**Less bad solution but still not happy with it**

```
_CAN_FIRE = {"Firearm": True}
_HAS_BLADE = {"Blade": True}

@poly_loader(Item, _CAN_FIRE)
class can_fire_extensions(Item):
    def attack(self):
        print("Firing!")

@poly_loader(Item, _HAS_BLADE)
class has_blade_extensions(Item):
    def attack(self):
        print("Attacking with blade!")
```

Comment: What do you want to have in the long run? Multiple types of items? (Like blade, pistol, axe, etc..). The attack function should be different depending of the type of the item?

Comment: Classes are probably not well-suited to this problem. You might be able to use mixin classes (which is very awkward and doesn't really mix together) or a metaclass, but you're probably best off making some sort of dispatch table for each property.

Comment: I wonder if this may better fit on [codereview.se] or [cs.se].

Comment: A big advantage to using some sort of dispatch table rules system is that you'd be able to store item attributes in a json file so you're not hardcoding this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to approach this...

## Use Inheritance, including Multiple Inheritance

In addition to subclassing `Item` into `Weapon` and `Shield`, `Weapon` into `Blade` and `Firearm` and so forth, you can create separate classes that just have one method and expect there to be certain attributes.

```
class Shootable(object):
    def aim(self):
        self.find_target()
    def fire(self):
        self.attack()
        # some more stuff
```

Then `Pistol` might look something like this:

```
class Pistol(Item, Shootable):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # Whatever goes here
```

## Don't Use Classes at all

There's one thing that classes don't solve well at all: cross-cutting concerns. Imagine you had something that was both a blade and a shield. Or a weapon that has both stealth effects and elemental effects- both of which apply to the `attack` action.

As far as I can tell, your items are essentially just data containers. You're probably better off keeping functionality in a function. You can use dictionaries to define rules via a dispatch table. For instance:

```
ItemRules = {
    ('Blade', True): blade_behavior,
    ('Firearm', True): firearm_behavior,
    ('Shield', True): shield_behavior,
    ('Type', 'stealth'): stealth_behavior
}
```

`blade_behavior`, `firearm_behavior`, and `shield_behavior` would each be functions or classes or something that define the appropriate behavior. So your rules engine would match the item definition for `'Blade'` being `True` and then run the appropriate code for that scenario. This has the benefit that if an item matches multiple rules, it can run the behavior for all of them. This makes it trivial to add an item that is both a `Firearm` and a `Blade`- just so long as you have tested that combination. You may end up needing a priority system in your rules engine to properly resolve weird cases, but that's something you'll have to figure out as you keep adding to your system.

The big advantage to this approach is that you can keep your item data completely separate from code, making it really easy to add new items that are only slightly different.

If you find this explanation confusing, I can come up with a Github gist of a more fleshed-out implementation to explain what I mean.